# IONIC Cordova app is giving android exported error

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, ionic-framework, ionic3

We have an app developed using IONIC CORDOVA. When I am trying to upload app on the play store then it gives an error
"Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for android:exported"

I am using cordova-android: 8.0.0

If I am using cordova-android:10.1.0 then I am unable to build app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this by adding android:exported: true to manifest.xml

`<intent-filter android:exported="true" android:label="@string/launcher_name">`

Please note that this error is related to launcher activity intent only

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issues. Im not sure what causes the issues I think it is an cordova one. But you can resolve it by going to the platforms/android/app/manifests/androidManifest.xml there is a section <activity. Add android:exported="true".
It should look like this <activity android:exported="true" ....(other variables)

Add android:exported="true", in your AndroidManifest.xml

eg:

```
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
        </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should update to cordova-android 11. This release features support for Android 12 and the latest play store requirements.

https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2022/07/12/cordova-android-release-11.0.0.html